# Replace running NIFI template

Tags: apache-nifi

I uploaded a template via api and delete the old template but how do I replace what is running currently. I see you can remove flow.xml but that needs a reboot. Is there any other way to replace a currently running template with a new one.

Answer (score 3):

There is no real link between a running flow and a template...

When you upload a template to NiFi, the template is stored in the flow.xml.gz underneath the process group where you uploaded it (assuming 1.x NiFi).

When you create a flow from a template, NiFi creates real components based on the template, but afterwards NiFi has no more link that those components came from a given template.

Lets say your template contained a single process group with components underneath it, and now you have created a flow based on that template...

You would have to write a script that uses the REST API to stop all components in that process group, then delete the entire process group, then recreate the flow from the new version of the template.

Templates were never really intended to be used for deployment, they were just a way to share a part of a flow with someone. The community is working on features around deployment of "versioned flows" which will help with these scenarios. You can read more here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Configuration+Management+of+Flows